# How to implement Post-Redirect-Get pattern in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post-redirect-get

I am having a form and in submission page.  When I refresh the page it asks for resend data. To avoid that I found that I have to implement PRG pattern.  Can anyone please help me to implement the same in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Do you need/want to also use codeigniter form_validation?

Comment: No i dont need validation

Comment: Then it is much easier. Give me a few to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass data from the processing function back to the viewing function you will have to use sessions. The example assumes Codeigniter v3.0.0 or greater. If you are using some earlier version you will have to modify the setting, getting and resetting of the session data.

Here's a very simple controller

```
class TestPRG extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('session');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $data['name'] = $this->session->name;
    $data['pw'] = $this->session->pw;
    $this->load->view('test_form_v', $data);
    unset($_SESSION['name'], $_SESSION['pw']);
  }

  public function process_form()
  {
   $_SESSION['name'] = $this->input->post('username');
   $_SESSION['pw'] = $this->input->post('password');
   redirect('testprg', 'location', 303);
  }

}
```

The view file

```
<?php    
echo form_open('testprg/process_form');
echo form_input('username', isset($name) ? $name : NULL);
echo form_password('password', "");
echo form_submit('Submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close();
echo isset($pw) ? $pw : "";
```

This will echo the last entered password if it exists. It won't exist on a page refresh or go back from the browser.